# Detect in Windows when I turn off my TV

Tags: windows, television, hdmi

I have a Windows PC connected to TV, and I need to detect when user put TV in standby mode.
I use WMIC function and works fine in old TV's, but the new model of TV's doesn't cut the power off HDMI ports, and windows say that TV is connected even when is in standby.
There is any way to detect that event, in any language??? (batch file, java, python, .net, etc) anything.

Answer (score 1):

If the TV is still recognized as connected, there is no event which is triggered when the tv is put in standby. So there is nothing to observe for a program. Try to work your way through the energy-settings of your tv or try to cut the power to the tv. Maybe it's shown as disconnected then.